Verification of Yudhishthira's dialogue on chastity in 'Practice of Brahmacharya' by Sivananda
In the book Practice of Brahmacharya by Sri Swami Sivananda, there is an account that seems unbelievable and difficult to imagine, particularly regarding the words attributed to Yudhishthira:

There is no denying, however, that lust is a powerful force to
overcome. Somebody asked Raja Yudhishthira, “O Yudhishthira, when you
look at your mother Kunti, is your look absolutely chaste?”
Yudhishthira replied, “I cannot say that my look is entirely pure.”
Such is the force of lust.
How to counter impure thoughts, 17. STOP THAT LUSTFUL
LOOK!

I am seeking an authentic scriptural reference for this statement attributed to Yudhishthira. Given that many statements by Sri Swami Sivananda are rooted in scripture, I would like to verify this particular dialogue.
Can anyone provide a source or reference from the original texts that supports this dialogue?

Can't imagine it to be from Vyasa's Mahabharata where the supreme character of King Yudhisthira is described many times.

Lord Krishna said, I desire, O Sanjaya, that Pandu's sons grow in
prosperity and not suffer. I also pray for the prosperity of the Kurus
as well. However, there cannot be peace as long as Dhritarastra's sons
are envious of the Pandavas. How can you say that Yudhisthira is
unmindful of his duties? How can you say that his desire for his
kingdom is a desire of lust? Yudhisthira is ever mindful of his
duties, and has never even known lust or wickedness in his heart.

Udyoga Parva Chapter 2.


